# selecting an element in xml using linq extension methods

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I am little new to linq and was wondering how i can select the application in the following xml based on the application name using *Extension Methods* (not using the query expression)

```
<applicationlist>
<application>
    <name>test1</name>
    <ele1>852</ele1
    <ele2>http://localhost/test1</ele2>
</application>

<application>
    <name>test2</name>
    <ele1>456</ele1
    <ele2>http://localhost/test2</ele2>
</application>
</applicationlist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by "the SQL way of selecting" you mean "using a query expression", let's start off with your query expression:

```
var v = from b in root.Descendants("application")
      where b.Element("name").Value.Trim().ToLower() == appName.Trim().ToLower()
      select b;
```

With extension methods, this would just be:

```
var v = root.Descendants("application")
            .Where(b => b.Element("name").Value.Trim().ToLower() ==
                        appName.Trim().ToLower());
```

I would recommend against making case-insensitive comparisons this way though - it has cultural problems. Use something like this instead:

```
var v = root.Descendants("application")
            .Where(b => b.Element("name").Value.Trim().Equals(appName.Trim(),
                                     StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

(or one of the other `StringComparison` options - or an instance of `StringComparer`).

You might also want to trim `appName` *once* rather than for every comparison...

Comment: That is a wonderful explanation. Thanks a lot. Edited my question also to frame it properly.